# Double spacing in rmarkdown pdf

Tags: r, r-markdown

I use the following in Rmarkdown YAML for double space (there are other items in the YAML that I do not include here).

```
output: pdf_document
header-includes:
    - \usepackage{setspace}\doublespacing
```

But it double spaces everything, but I want not to double space in the **title** page. My **title** page contains title of the document (which is more than 2 lines), author affiliations (which is also several lines).

Please note that my output is pdf (not HTML or WORD doc). Other components in YAML is fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Move your `\doublespacing` command out of the header and use where you need it:

````
---
output: pdf_document
header-includes:
  - \usepackage{setspace}
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

# Single Spacing

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, fermentum parturient luctus pretium sodales, porta iaculis massa sed nisl turpis, metus eget. Eu tincidunt est blandit. In gravida, tempus libero convallis leo suscipit tincidunt sit. Senectus eros, vel tincidunt conubia primis, sagittis phasellus laoreet ac. Sed ut non semper feugiat feugiat montes erat. Ultricies, turpis dictumst, ante, tempor orci elementum nam in ac. Justo facilisis nibh nibh at donec porta. Ultrices, interdum accumsan sociis mi. Ligula iaculis molestie eu pellentesque eu. Leo rutrum pulvinar ut egestas himenaeos quisque, in parturient, nec non commodo vel diam. Donec nec praesent lacus morbi nisi risus nec. Sit, ipsum, tincidunt ornare a dis ac, aliquam elit.

# Double Spacing

\doublespacing

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, fermentum parturient luctus pretium sodales, porta iaculis massa sed nisl turpis, metus eget. Eu tincidunt est blandit. In gravida, tempus libero convallis leo suscipit tincidunt sit. Senectus eros, vel tincidunt conubia primis, sagittis phasellus laoreet ac. Sed ut non semper feugiat feugiat montes erat. Ultricies, turpis dictumst, ante, tempor orci elementum nam in ac. Justo facilisis nibh nibh at donec porta. Ultrices, interdum accumsan sociis mi. Ligula iaculis molestie eu pellentesque eu. Leo rutrum pulvinar ut egestas himenaeos quisque, in parturient, nec non commodo vel diam. Donec nec praesent lacus morbi nisi risus nec. Sit, ipsum, tincidunt ornare a dis ac, aliquam elit.

\singlespacing

# Single Spacing

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, fermentum parturient luctus pretium sodales, porta iaculis massa sed nisl turpis, metus eget. Eu tincidunt est blandit. In gravida, tempus libero convallis leo suscipit tincidunt sit. Senectus eros, vel tincidunt conubia primis, sagittis phasellus laoreet ac. Sed ut non semper feugiat feugiat montes erat. Ultricies, turpis dictumst, ante, tempor orci elementum nam in ac. Justo facilisis nibh nibh at donec porta. Ultrices, interdum accumsan sociis mi. Ligula iaculis molestie eu pellentesque eu. Leo rutrum pulvinar ut egestas himenaeos quisque, in parturient, nec non commodo vel diam. Donec nec praesent lacus morbi nisi risus nec. Sit, ipsum, tincidunt ornare a dis ac, aliquam elit.
````

[image]