# Avoid double spacing in Rmarkdown pdf (within chunk)

Tags: r, pdf, latex, r-markdown, line-spacing

I am trying to make my own APA7 style Rmarkdown template (with pdf output). Feel pretty good so far. The only thing left for me to fix is the double spacing in code chunks.

I have quickly found this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66147656/double-spacing-in-rmarkdown-pdf) which resolves the issue on how to double space with the following code.

```
header-includes:
    - \usepackage{setspace}\doublespacing
```

However, the double spacing also apply to code chunks which I would prefer them to be single space. I know I could add something like `\singlespacing` before and after the chunks, but since I use many chucks, is there a cleverer way?

It there a way to avoid the double spacing produced by `\doublespacing` in code chunks?

---

EDIT

Here is a reproducible example.

````
---
output: pdf_document
header-includes:
  - \usepackage{setspace}\doublespacing
---

I am trying to make my own APA7 style Rmarkdown template (with pdf output). Feel pretty good so far. The only thing left for me to fix is the double spacing in code chunks.

```{r}
# This chuck is also double spaced
# But I would prefer it to be single spaces
```
````

[image]

Comment: Can you please make a [mre]? You could patch the environment, which sets the chunks, to automatically add the `\singlespacing`

Comment: Done @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz. I don't know how to achieve what you suggest though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rmarkdown defines a `Shaded` environment, which is used to set these code snippets. You can patch it to automatically add `\singlespace`:

````
---
output: 
  pdf_document:
    keep_tex: true
header-includes:
  - \usepackage{setspace}\doublespacing
  - \usepackage{etoolbox}
  - \AtBeginEnvironment{Shaded}{\singlespace}
---

I am trying to make my own APA7 style Rmarkdown template (with pdf output). Feel pretty good so far. The only thing left for me to fix is the double spacing in code chunks.

```{r}
# This chuck is also double spaced
# But I would prefer it to be single spaces
```
I am trying to make my own APA7 style Rmarkdown template (with pdf output). Feel pretty good so far. The only thing left for me to fix is the double spacing in code chunks.
````

[image]

Comment: @POC You're welcome!

Comment: Would anyone happen to know how to get the main headers to single space?  I tried using this example with:

## Header 1
## Header 2 on single spaced line

But this seems to continue to double-space.  Thanks, in advance, for any suggestions.

Comment: @StatsStudent If you have a new question, please use the "Ask Question" button at the top right